# KTA Workqueue queries

Tags: kofax

In work queue is it possible to create new custom columns?

For example right now we have columns like JobID, Process Version, SLA, Activity Name, Process .... Just wondering is possible to add fields like create name, creation date ...

Let me be more specific. In KTA, when we create new Work Queue queries, in the columns tab/section there is an option to select or show the columns like SLA, Activity Name, Job ID, Process, Priority, Due Date, Assigned To and more.

**My question, Is it possible to add new columns to the original list like create name, job creation date and more?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use (Designer > Data) Work Types to accomplish this. You'll need to set up the work type with the variables you'd like to be able to see and then assign the Work Type to the process under the General tab on your process Properties. Assign data to the (Work Type) variable(s) with an action on the form (.NET, Assembly File Path: TotalAgility SDK, Class: JobService, Method: UpdateJobVariables) or an Expression Node on the process.

Comment: Hi Dave, Thank you very much for the information. I was able custom columns to work queue queries by creating new work types.